# How to nest output dataframe from for loop in existing dataframe in R

Tags: r, dataframe, for-loop, nested-lists

I have a dataframe on members of the US congress and I'm am collecting additional data from google trends using the gtrendsR package. Given that google trends won't allow me to search all members of congress in a single query, I've decided to create a ForLoop that collects the data for one politician at a time.

```
for (i in df$name_google){
  user <- i
  res <- gtrends(c(obama, user), geo = c("US"), time = "all")
}
```

However, the google trends output file (`res`) is itself a list with a number of dataframes.

[image]

I would like to use the for loop to save this list to a new column in `df`, with each iteration of the loop adding the new res file to the row the of the user it just searched. I don't know how to do this, but something like the line i added to the lop below. Let me know if I'm failing to include necessary info.

```
for (i in df$name_google){
  user <- i
  res <- gtrends(c(obama, user), geo = c("US"), time = "all")
#df$newlistvariable <- res  if df$name == i
}
```

Comment: Simply turn the `for` to an apply function that returns list equal to length of iterations: `df$newlistvariable <- lapply(df$name_google, function(i) gtrends(c(obama, i), geo=c("US"), time="all"))`.

Comment: However, I would advise not saving nested structures within data frames. Keep columns in data frames as atomic, primitive types (`logical`, `integer`, `numeric`, `character`). Use general lists for complex, nested, and mixed elements.

Comment: Thanks @Parfait. How do I tun a loop into a function?

Comment: Hmmm...Did you run the above `lapply` function? Apply methods are loops.